# hide elements with name using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, jquery-selectors

I am using backbone and

I have following code in template

```
    <a class="al_ynbtn apv_app" id="approveLeave" name=<%=leave_request_id%>></a>
    <a class="al_ynbtn can_app" id="rejectLeave" name=<%=leave_request_id%>></a>
```

and in render function i have following code

```
  render: function() {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));
        var selectedElem='[name='+self.model.leave_request_id+']';
            console.log(selectedElem);
            console.log($(selectedElem));
            //$("a[name='"self.model.leave_request_id+"']" )
            $(selectedElem).hide();


        return this.el;
    }
```

console.log(selectedElem) prints  [name=3257]

and console.log($(selectedElem)) prints

[a#approveLeave.al_ynbtn.apv_app, a#rejectLeave.al_ynbtn.can_app, prevObject: m.fn.init[1], context: document, selector: "[name=3257]", jquery: "1.11.1", constructor: function…]
0: a#approveLeave.al_ynbtn.apv_app
1: a#rejectLeave.al_ynbtn.can_app
context: document
length: 2
prevObject: m.fn.init[1]
selector: "[name=3257]"
**proto**: Object[0]

i want to hide elements with name=3257?  how to do that?

Comment: selectedElem is printed correct but elements are not hidden with $(selectedElem).hide(). is there anything wrong related to concatenation?

Comment: Not sure exactly what is wrong - I think there is an issue elsewhere in your code. I simplified the code to just query by the name and it works fine. see http://jsfiddle.net/rbGfg/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing quotes around your names:

```
<a class="al_ynbtn apv_app" id="approveLeave" name="<%=leave_request_id%>"></a>
<a class="al_ynbtn can_app" id="rejectLeave" name="<%=leave_request_id%>"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jquery:

```
$('a').filter(function(){
    return this.name === '3257';
}).hide();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
render: function() {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model));
    var selectedElem='[name='+self.model.leave_request_id+']';
    //$('[name=\'3257\']').hide(); //Hardcoded name value
    $('[name=\'' + self.model.leave_request_id + '\']').hide();//jQuery cascades so you can call .hide() on the same line
    return this.el;
}
```